# Can one state and prove that Euclidean space has genus $0$ in Hilbert's geometry?

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

Related to a more [historically inclined question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7918/were-the-ancient-greeks-aware-of-the-topology-of-euclidean-space) I'd like to ask, if the language and axioms of [Hilbert's geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) do suffice to first state and then prove that in the standard model (Euclidean space) every circle can be (continuously) collapsed to a point, i.e. that Euclidean space has [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Topology) $0$. Or is this beyond Euclidean geometry?

(If it cannot be proved there must be models of genus $\neq 0$?)

Comment: I'm fairly sure I can't give a definitive answer this question, but regardless I think that some clarification is needed. What do you mean by proving Euclidean space has genus 0 in the language of Hilbert's geometry? I ask because continuity and continuous maps from the circle cross the interval to Euclidean space are definitely not notions of Hilbert's geometry. Continued below.

Comment: This is a crucial point though because geometric circles and topological circles do not coincide as notions at all. Consider the 2-torus with metric induced by the quotient $\Bbb{R}^2/\Bbb{Z}^2$. Then lines of rational slope are topologically circles, but not geometrically. Moreover, every geometric circle can be continuously contracted to a point, since geometric circles are the images of geometric circles in $\Bbb{R}^2$. However the torus of course doesn't have genus 0. (Depending on how you define circles in a Riemannian manifold I guess. I don't do much Riemannian geometry.)

Comment: @jgon: Would geometric and topological *closed curves* coincide?

Comment: I'm not sure. More precisely, I'm not sure how one would define a geometric closed curve in the language of Hilbert's geometry.

Comment: This may be recklessly naive, but wouldn't it be as simple as proving:  Given any circle $C$ with center $O$ and radius $R$, and given any $0<r<R$, there exists a circle centered at $O$ with radius $r$? That seems to capture the idea of "a circle can be collapsed to a point" pretty naturally without needing to formally define continuity.

Comment: @mweiss: That's how I motivated my question at HSM: [Were the ancient Greeks aware of the topology of (Euclidean) space?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7918/were-the-ancient-greeks-aware-of-the-topology-of-euclidean-space).